# Find time at which a certain distance occurs between moving objects

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

I have two objects moving away in space whose positions given by $r_1$ and $r_2$, their velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ and relative vectors R=$r_2$-$r_1$ and V=$v_2$-$v_1$. How to find the time at which these objects are separated by a distance D?. Assuming radial velocity, $V_r$ is $\frac{R \cdot V}{\vert R\vert} $
Is $\frac{D-d_0}{V_r}$ correct formula, $d_0$ being initial distance between points?

For example, $r_1$ = [3,8], $r_2$ = [5,4], $v_1$ = [-1,1], $v_2$ = [1,1], then how to find time at which they are separated by distance 10? The results differ from simple enumeration of their positions over time using $r+v \cdot t$ and finding distance and interpolating between them. What am I missing?

Comment: You can use MathJax to typeset mathematics on this website. [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: $D=|R|=|r_1-r_2|=$ $|r_{1,0}+v_1t-r_{2,0}-v_2t|=$ $|(r_{1,0}-r_{2,0}+(v_1-v_2)t)|=$ $|R_0+Vt|$. $D^2=(R_0+Vt)^2=R_0^2+2R_0\cdot Vt+V^2t^2$. You can solve for $t$. This is square equation, so linear formula is incorrect. It is due to the fact that $V_r=\frac{R\cdot V}{|R|}$ is varying with time. In simplest case of one dimensional motion $V_r$ is constant so linear formula does work